# Thermodynamics - Partial Derivatives

Tags: thermodynamics, differentiation

I just need help to solve a problem:

$\left(\frac{∂\overline{E}}{∂V}\right)_{β,N} + β\left(\frac{∂\overline{p}}{∂β}\right)_{N,V} = - \overline{p}$

PS: The bar over E and over p (this in both sides) means that is an average.

I don't know how to start, so any help will be amazing. I'm not a physicist, so I'm having a bad time trying to solve this.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What is the problem? You are showing an equation... what are you expecting people here to do with it? Is this a homework assignment? Have you taken a look at the help center and read the article on "what kinds of questions can I ask here?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you very slowly increase the volume of an isolated system, then the internal energy will drop. The ratio between the drop in energy and the volume increase is, by definition, the pressure. The system can be in one of many possible energy levels, these energy levels decrease if we increase the volume (the larger the volume of a system the more closely packed will the energy levels be). If you very slowly increase the volume then the system will remain in whatever energy level it was, the energy will then drop simply because the energy level itself is going down in energy.

A system that is kept at some temperature with temperature parameter $\beta = \frac{1}{k_B T}$. will have a probability $P_r$ of being in a state with energy $E_r$ of:

$$P_r = \frac{\exp(-\beta E_r)}{Z}$$

where $Z$, the so-called partition function is the normalization to make the sum of all the probabilities equal to 1:

$$Z = \sum_r \exp(-\beta E_r)$$

It then follows that the expectation value of the energy is given by:

$$\bar{E} = -\frac{\partial \log{Z}}{\partial\beta}$$

and the pressure is:

$$\bar{p} = \frac{1}{\beta}\frac{\partial \log{Z}}{\partial V}$$

Note that the energy levels $E_r$ are functions of the volume, the above formula yields precisely the expectation value of minus the partial derivative of the energy that defines the pressure.

If you substitute these expressions in the left hand side of the equation in your problem, you see that you get second derivatives, you can then use the [symmetry of second derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives) to change the order of differentiation and then simplify the expression.